# Getting error with mail attachment when user does not want photo

Tags: php, html

I've got a cake order form for my website and part of it allows the user to decide whether or not they want a photo on their cake. When they complete the form and it is confirmed the order is created on my sql table and they are sent an email confirmation, in the email is an attached pdf and the photo they want (if they choose to have one). This works if they do want a photo but I get an error if they decide they don't want one.

This is the html for the photo part of the form:

```
<p>Would you like a photo on your cake?(£7)</p>
<div>
<label class="checkbox-inline"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="photo[]" class="photo" id="photo[]" value="7">Yes
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="radio" name="photo[]" class="photo" id="photo[]" value="0"/>No
</div>

</label>
<br /><br />
<div class="7 box" style="display: none;">
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*"/>
 <img id="cakePhoto" src="#" />

 </div>

 <div class="0 box" style="display: none;">
 <p>You do not want a photo on your cake</p>
 </div>
```

The reason for the div classes is because one will appear depending on what the user decides, if they choose yes then the file input appears, but if they choose no then the "You do not want a photo on your cake" appears

I am using $_SESSION for storing the values as I need them on a couple different pages but this is how I am storing the photo uploaded by the user:

```
$filename    = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
  $destination = "uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]; 
 move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination); //save uploaded picture to directory

    $_SESSION['photo'] = $destination;
```

For sending the email I am attaching the photo like so:

```
$mail->addAttachment($_SESSION['photo']);
```

Like I said this works if the user has decided to upload file but if they do not then I get the following error:

Could not access file: uploads/

Is there a way I can get around this? I was thinking of perhaps something like an if statement for if the photo exists then attach it but I'm really not sure how I would go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: I've tried the suggestion given by droopsnoot but it is still not working so I've played about with it and tried testing it by doing the following:

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) { 
  $filename    = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
  $destination = "uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]; 
  move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination); //save uploaded picture to directory
  $_SESSION['photo'] = $destination;
} else {
unset($_SESSION['photo']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['photo'])) { 
echo ($_SESSION['photo']);
} else {
    echo "No photo chosen";
}
```

If no is selected for choosing an image it still shows: uploads/
so this would suggest that unset is not working, what could be done to sort this?

Comment: If they did not upload an image, then `$_FILES["image"]` will be empty to begin with. You should check that, before you try to write stuff into your session that is likely not even set, and even try to move an uploaded file that _was_ never even uploaded. And then you simply check again if your session actually contains any file info, before you call the method that tries to attach a file …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some more research into this I found that a number of people have had issues with using isset when determining whether an image has been uploaded or not. Seems that it still thinks that it is set even when null so a solution that I found that now works for me is as follows:

For finding out if a photo has been uploaded or not:

```
if (!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['photo']);

}else{
  $filename    = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
  $destination = "uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]; 
  move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination); //save uploaded picture to directory
  $_SESSION['photo'] = $destination;

}
```

and then in the mail part for uploading I have kept it the same as to the solution droopsnoot kindly provided:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['photo'])) { 
  $mail->addAttachment($_SESSION['photo']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always check whether or not an image has been uploaded (like you should check all other form variables) and only try to move the image, and use it as an attachment, if there is one.

You're getting that error message because the code, without an image name, is referring to the entire directory, which you can't use in the same way. You should only set the session variable (or however you refer to the image file) if one is uploaded, and only add it as an attachment if it's present.

So

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"} { 
  $filename    = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
  $destination = "uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]; 
  move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination); //save uploaded picture to directory
  $_SESSION['photo'] = $destination;
} else {
unset($_SESSION['photo']);
}
```

and

```
if (isset($_SESSION['photo'])) { 
  $mail->addAttachment($_SESSION['photo']);
}
```

Comment: thank you but this for some reason is not working, there are no errors now but when a photo is uploaded it is not attached to the email, it does save to the uploads directory though

Comment: also just so you know I got errors originally as you forgot the closing )) and also used } instead of ] after tmp_name on the first line

Comment: okay so turns out I was putting the first bit of code in the wrong area, wasn't actually uploading to uploads, but by putting it in the correct place I am still getting the original can't access uploads error

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but the code for putting the image into the uploads directory is in a separate page to the one which sends the email

Comment: I think it must be the unset($_SESSION['photo']); that is not working

Comment: OK, instead of using `unset`, what about setting it to a blank string, and check for that as well as whether the variable exists?

Comment: hi, sorry just seen this now, tried that but still isn't doing anything

Comment: so I tried changing   $_SESSION['photo'] = $destination;, to unset($_SESSION['photo']); and that does unset it so I'm presuming that maybe something else needs to be said other than just } else { ?

Comment: You did put that second bit of my code around the part where you're adding the attachment to the email, not immediately after the image uploading code as you show above?

Comment: Some more detail would be appreciated, in case it helps anyone else in the future who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (isset($_SESSION['photo']) && file_exists($_SESSION['photo'])) {
    $mail->addAttachment($_SESSION['photo']);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately still getting the same error using this